# Minus the quantity of product of same I'd from different table

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two table product and cart.
Product table contains

| Prod ID. | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | 5 |
| 2. | 4 |

Cart table contains

| Cart I'd | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

I want to minus  Cart table quantity of two same cart I'd 1 from product table I'd 1.

I tried this

```
for row in cartlist:
      Cartlist=[Cid, quantity]
      PQ= row[1]
   for rows in p.get_children():
      Q1= p.item()[1]
      if cid == pid:
         Addqty=Q1 + PQ
   c.execute('Update product set q1=? where PID?),(Addqty))
```

I need output as:
Product table:

| Prod ID | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 |

Comment: What is your problem actually?  Any error shown in console? It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: I am getting no errors, just one I'd quantity is adding into table, I need to add every same I'd of quantity to table

Comment: Not minus I want to add the product

Comment: I am getting output like this
Prodid        Quantity 
1.                      7
2.                      4

Comment: You should get error because the SQL is incorrect.  Also there are many unknown stuff: What are `Cid` and `quantity` in the line `Cartlist=[Cid, quantity]` and `Cartlist` is not used; What is `p`? It looks like a treeview.  So what you say *tables* are treeview tables or database tables, etc.  Once again, it is better to provide a [mre], otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: p is treeview table
Instead of cartlist I used entry now
PQ= quantity.get() # from entry 
   for rows in p.get_children(): # treeview